# How to react on the dynamically generated button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I add the button with the following code:

```
$('.dishes').prepend($('<div class="row" data-dishid="'+dishid+'"><div class="col-md-8">'+dishname+'<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>'));
```

But the following code doesn't catch the button click (when it works with the same code if it is part of the static html):

```
$("button.close").click(function() {
      var row = $(this).closest('.row');
      var dishid = row.attr('data-dishid');      
});
```

How can I fix that?

See [the sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/3k7Laohn/1/).

Comment: It's obviously a duplicate and should be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the code. You have to call the click function of the dynamic element immediately after the element appended. Try the code below.

```
$("#add").on('click', function() {
    $('.dishes').prepend($('<div class="row" data-dishid="'+ "test" +'"><div class="col-md-8">'+ " test " +'<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>'));
    $("button.close").on('click', function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('.row');
        var dishid = row.attr('data-dishid');      
        console.log(dishid);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For dynamically created elements, you should use `.on('click', selector, callback)`

like

```
$(document).on("click", "button.close", function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var dishid = row.attr('data-dishid');      
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question - looks like the problem not only with reacting on 'click' event, but also with getting element's attribute.

Comment: @LA_ You also need to bind ``button.close`` with ``on``

Answer (score 3):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated element. Try like following.

```
$(document).on('click', "button.close", function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('.row');
    var dishid = row.attr('data-dishid');
    console.log(dishid);
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3k7Laohn/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button.close").on("click", function(){
   console.log('ok');
});
```

You need to use on() function for dynamically generated html elements

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("button.close").on("click", function() {
  console.log('ok');
});
```

You need the .on event handler for dynamically created DOM elements.

UPDATE:

you don't need to put jQuery `$` before the content of the prepend. Here is a working fiddle with your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/3k7Laohn/

Comment: Thank you. I use `$` because I also animate the element addition (what I've removed from my sample code). But it really doesn't affect how it works. But your code doesn't work with my code, since I add the element on button click and not during page load - https://jsfiddle.net/3k7Laohn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/3k7Laohn/4/).

I changed:

```
$("button.close").click(function() {
      var row = $(this).closest('.row');
      var dishid = row.attr('data-dishid');      
});
```

To:

```
$(".dishes").on('click', 'button.close', function() {
      var row = $(this).closest('.row');
      var dishid = row.attr('data-dishid');      
      console.log(dishid);
});
```

This question is answered all over the internet and here is a snippet from jQuery's site:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on(). Alternatively, use delegated events to attach event
>   handlers.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/on/%20)

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking your code, the click event should be working fine. Maybe the problem relies on the **timing**. My assumption is if you have the code below:

```
$("button.close").click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var dishid = row.attr('data-dishid');
});
```

You haven't appended the object yet on the DOM. Everytime you call the method below, you have to immediately bind the click event. Best is to have the codes together to check if it will work.

```
$('.dishes').prepend($('<div class="row" data-dishid="'+dishid+'"><div class="col-md-8">'+dishname+'<button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></div>'));
$("button.close").click(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var dishid = row.attr('data-dishid');
});
```